# Can you share Azure storage account for NServiceBus Sub Storage, DataBus and Saga?

Tags: azure, soa, nservicebus, azure-storage

How does NServiceBus reserve the storage on Azure for the purposes of Subscription storage, Databus and Saga?

Do I need a separate account for each of the NServiceBus hub in my solution or can they all live with one storage account?

I honestly prefer that NServiceBus manages the storage account and let it be shared among various services, but I couldn't find any documentation on the matter.

Eg. If NServiceBus prefix all storage container with the queue name, then they all can live with one storage account, if not the chances of the various services stepping on each others toe is great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSB has been designed so that every construct has it's own connection string to a storage account, that said, I typically start out with the same account for everything and haven't noticed any 'stepping on each others toe' so far.

If you do let me know!

Kind regards,
Yves